# How to reset uploadcare widget after failed validation?

Tags: javascript, uploadcare

I restrict uploaded file type following [official docs](https://uploadcare.com/cookbook/validation/). It works fine.

But then I just can't reset it. `widget.value(null)` works fine when I need to reset widget after successful uploading, but it doesn't work when I try to clear error message. Is there any way to **completely** reset widget?

**Update**: Example on [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hJuqBfX7OkdTOKXVbgAL?p=preview).

Comment: Could you provide an example? Actually, I can't reproduce this.

Comment: @homm, surely. Updated question with example on Plunker.